# How to cause a subform to update in Access after filling in a combobox on the main form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a Query that I am using to fill in data on a subform. The query references in its WHERE statement two hidden textboxes on the main form:

```
SELECT *
FROM qun_TrainingSU
WHERE ([qun_TrainingSU].[Training]=[Forms]![TrainingsSU]![htxt_Training]) AND (EmployeeInformation.Employee = Forms!TrainingsSU!htxt_Employee);
```

The qun_TrainingSU query is a complicated union query of the format :

```
SELECT CompletedTrainingsNew.Employee, CompletedTrainingsNew.AbuseNeglect AS Compdate, AbuseNeglect+(SELECT Expdays 
FROM Trainings 
WHERE Trainings.[Training Name] = "Abuse & Neglect"
) AS Expired, EmployeeInformation.[Last Name], EmployeeInformation.Employee, "Abuse & Neglect" AS Training
FROM EmployeeInformation INNER JOIN CompletedTrainingsNew ON EmployeeInformation.ID = CompletedTrainingsNew.Employee
WHERE ((([AbuseNeglect]+(SELECT Expdays 
FROM Trainings 
WHERE Trainings.[Training Name] = "Abuse & Neglect" ))))
```

With 22 other different trainings being unioned to this exact one. They are programatically identical, with only text changes as needed to change the various names of the different required trainings.

Both queries work alone. They are flawless (if amatureish) in functionality.

What I want to do, is create a subform on the main form, that calls the first query I listed, and allows for editing the records as need be.

I have tried going into the property sheet for the subform and doing links:
I have two combo boxes that fill the two hidden text boxes (htxt_Employee, htxt_Training)
I named the as Master (seen in the image below) and I referenced them to fields in the query as Child Fields.

[image: Link Fields image]

Now, I *think* my problem is that I need to get the subform to update after both boxes are selected, so that the data in question shows up. And if that is the case, I need to know how to do that. I've looked, and I have found some stuff on manually updating the boxes, that may work for **me** but I am not the end user, and I need this to be pretty much automatic for them.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: `Me!mySubform.Requery`

Comment: Not being a VBA coder here, should that be in the "After Update" section of the combo boxes? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes in the AfterUpdate

Comment: No need for hidden textboxes. If you use the two comboboxes as the masterfields, the subform will update automatically with zero code when changing a selection in the comboboxes.

Comment: "two combo boxes that fill the two hidden text boxes" - fill with what? Image shows reference to cbo_training in LinkMaster. Why not reference both comboboxes?

Comment: Use of a UNION query indicates non-normalized data structure. Not clear to me with this query is for. If subform is synchronized with main form using Master/Child links, why have dynamic parameter in subform query?